# control the TrackballControls

Tags: three.js

How one can restrict the rotation of the TrackballControl (r53) to, say, upper hemisphere? Or, more generally, how to restrict it to a single axis? I've seen this question is popping up from time to time but I cannot find a definitive answer. I've tried say controls.update( delta ); camera.position.z = 0; in render(), but it doesn't seem to work. I looked at the code for TrackBall, getMouseProjectionOnBall seems a good start, is this the right way? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please share jsfiddle for your issue ?

Comment: @Valay Please consider say https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_lightmap.html as an example. One should be able to restrict the rotation of the camera to above the ground only.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative to using TrackballControls (it was for me).

Add a 'master' Object3D object to your scene and instead of adding your objects to the scene, add them to the 'master' object.
That way you can just use the rotation code from one of the examples to rotate the 'master' object and everything will rotate with it.